# How can I post updates for deleted records using TEMSDataSetResource in RAD Server 11

Tags: delphi, firebird, firebird-3.0, ems, delphi-11-alexandria

I have created a simple new Rad Server Package with resource with a data module to access a Firebird 3.05 database running on Ubuntu 18.0.4. I included sample endpoints and a database endpoint with one table from the database.

I modified the created FDQuery to return a subset of the records.

```sql
select * from EXPENSES where COMPANYID = :COMPANYID
```

It indicated the FireDACFBDriver was not found, and instead of adding the PhysFBDriverLink, I deleted the FireDACFBDriver in the project source and it asked to add back the FireDACIBDriver and it works. This is besides the point, I think, but just full disclosure. I have tried the PhysFBLink with same results, but have had trouble switching back and forth to Linux deploy, so this works for testing I believe.

The client app consists of a TEMSFireDACClient, a FDSchemaAdapter, FD TAble Adapter, FDMemTable and datasource and dbgrid and three buttons.

Button1

```pascal
Expenses.GetEndpoint.Params.Clear()
expenses.GetEndpoint.Params.AddItem(
  'CompanyID','10000080');
Expenses.GetData();
```

Button2

```pascal
FDMemTable1.delete;
```

Button3

```pascal
Expenses.GetEndpoint.Params.Clear();
expenses.GetEndpoint.Params.AddItem(
  'CompanyID','10000080');
Expenses.PostUpdates;
```

Button One retrieves multiple rows, and button two deletes a row locally, and button 3 tries to apply the table updates back to the server.

When attempting to post updates. I get the following error:

> EMS Error: Resource error. Request parameter not found: COMPANYID.

This works when the resource SQL is `SELECT * FROM EXPENSES`. Is it just that the TEMSDataSetResources can only work on the full table, or Is there something simple I am missing or a reference available for how to accomplish this?

I have tried creating a manual delete endpoint with:

```sql
delete from EXPENSES where EXPENSEID = #####
```

However, that is another post maybe if I have to go there. I cannot get around and error converting Unicode to integer variant when passing the parameter.